# Stop/Resume jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have alert/confirm boxes in a function and then I use custom alert boxes instead of the system's alert/ confirm boxes.
I want the same functionality as the system's alert/confirm boxes have.
Like once I show my custom alert popup it stops the function in which I call that popup and when I click Ok after confirmation it resumes that function again.

Also, I have multiple alerts and confirm boxes in a single function, So I want them to run in a proper manner in which the system's alert boxes run.

function startUp(){

```
if (errors != "")
{ 
    alert("$errors");
}


    if (confirm("$warning"))
    {
        document.modifyForm.submit();
    }
```

}

In this above example, I have 1 alert and 1 confirm box
by default when the alert came to the system stops the code's execution and then click OK or cancel then code resume

I want the same by using custom popup
When I put my popup instead of the alert box it does not stops the code. So, I want to stop the code and when I click OK or Cancel on my custom popup then code resume and it goes to confirm box after alert finished and then confirm box do the same.

Comment: You're going to have a custom popup, most likely an invisible div that is turned visible. It'll have a button with a click listener. One way to solve this is to pass a callback to your custom alert function that gets executed when the close button is clicked. Another way is to use a Promise, that way you can write "synchronous" code that'll await the clicking away of the alert, then continue the function but not freeze the browser. Have you tried *anything* yet?

Comment: no i didn't tried this

Comment: send me some example so i can understand better

Comment: Here's a Promise based version: https://jsfiddle.net/53stgf42/ (this is not how SO works though, you're supposed to do research, learn the necessary techniques and come up with your own attempt)